# Use hardware remotely

Tags: python, rpc, ethernet, lan

I have a software that runs on my PC.  There is a test setup elsewhere in the network which has  temperature and pressure measuring cards. That setup also has a windows OS.
Both my PC and the setup are connected to the LAN. Now I want to write a temperature measuring test on my PC using my software (written in python)  which would access the remote setup.
How can I achieve this? Previously I was running my software on the setup itself , using `windll` utitlty to initialize the cards and now I want to separate it out.

Comment: the device that has the sensors attached would need to provide the readings (via a socket server/ a web page/ a rest interface/ something else)

Comment: @JoranBeasley So does that mean I need to write a server process on the setup? Like I would send a command from my PC to that process and then the process would be responsible for setting up the card, making measurement and sending result?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using python you should consider fabric http://www.fabfile.org/ or the new incarnation this project, invoke http://www.pyinvoke.org/

Both of these allow you to run code remotely over an ssh connection.   I'm a mac/unix guy but I think they work with windows.

Comment: Is this utility to call some code in the remote machine?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it connects to the remote machine via ssh and then executes commands which can be defined on the client machine.

Like ftp-ing your script over to the remote and then logging into that remote to exec it.

Answer (score 0):

If the set up is proving a LAN interface and exposes a server then it is possible to read the value using socket programming. If not then a web service can be run on the setup to read the value and serve it on the network

Comment: For socket programming, I should write a server on the remote machine? Currently I have nothing on the remote setup

Comment: The server has to be running  on the system where the setup is installed. The server program will read the value from hardware and send it to connected client system/remote system